The ring was put on in/at the wedding. - which is acceptable?
We use "in" when the subject is actively taking part in an event.
For example,

"The bride put on the ring in the wedding."

And when the subject is just a viewer or audience, we use "at."

"I ate lots of food at the wedding."

But when it is in passive voice and the subject is the ring, which one do we use in that case, in or at?
Example 1

The ring was put on in/at the wedding.

Similarly, "in class" means "learning in a classroom."
Usually, only student can learn in a classroom, so is the below example correct?
Example 2

The learning materials emphasize the importance of understanding inequality in class/in the classroom.


Tim Burton scored  the winning goal in the semi-finals . The winning goal was scored by Tim Burton in the semi-finals.

The materials ? Do you mean subjects?

@Mari-LouA sorry for the confusion. I wanted to say "learning materials."

I'm not sure about that rule. I think "at the wedding" sounds more natural in both sentences; similarly "at the party", "at the funeral".  You'd say "He gave a beautiful eulogy at the funeral" or "The bride wore such-and-such a dress at the wedding" (or maybe "to the wedding"?)

I don't think "when the subject is actively taking part in an event" is relevant to the choice of preposition. It's just that we don't usually use container metaphor in to introduce "events" like wedding, party, funeral,... Thus There were no children at the wedding, not ...in the wedding. But usage is flexible - you can see people in a meeting, or during or at a meeting, for example.

In class means 'in a classroom while a lesson is taking place'. There is nothing wrong with Example 2.

@FumbleFingers, There were no children in the wedding is perfectly acceptable. It means that the wedding ceremony didn’t include, for instance, adorable little flower girls or ring bearers.

@PaulTanenbaum: That's in your opinion. I don't accept the use of in there. And preposition in virtually "flatlines" by comparison with guest at the wedding. I'd accept in the wedding ceremony, though, provided it's a temporal rather than locational reference.

@FumbleFingers, sure, there’s some amount of subjectivity. But to the ear of this American, things like She has a closet full of gowns from all the weddings she’s been in are 100% acceptable. Indeed, that’s much more likely in my experience than …the wedding ceremonies she’s been in.  To be clear, be at a wedding suggests being a guest, while be in a wedding means play some role in the ceremony.


We use "in" when the subject is actively taking part in an event. For example,

This is not true.

"The bride put on the ring in the wedding."

This is an error, it should be
"The bride put on the ring during the wedding ceremony." or
"The bride put on the ring at the wedding ceremony."
"During" creates a time reference; "at" is locative (it tells you where the action occurred.)

But when it is in passive voice and the subject is the ring, which one do we use in that case, in or at?

This is also wrong: The voice of the verb makes no difference at all to the preposition:
"The ring was put on the bride during the wedding ceremony" / "The ring was put on the bride at the wedding ceremony."
in (preposition) - (i) within, inside (locative) "The dog is in the house." (ii) indicating motion (informally) = into "He ran in the room and shouted."

(sorry about the misdirected comment & dv)

at is not always locative.  at the appointed time.  Though I guess you could say it is a figurative use of the locative in a temporal context, a "point" on a "time line".

As you point out, "at" is locative in space and time.

"in the wedding" refers to the wedding ceremony.
"at the wedding" refers to the occasion.

When is the torch lit?
--In the opening ceremony.

Or

Did you see the torch get lit?
--Yes, at the opening ceremony.

